# problem with .Net xml importnode

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

Im trying to construct a powershell script that uses some XML. I have a XML document where I try to add some values with email addresses. The finished xml document should have this format:
(I'm only showing the relevant part of the xml here)

```
<emailAddresses> 
    <value>bob@bob.com</value> 
    <value>kenny@bob.com</value> 
    <value>roger@bob.com</value> 
</emailAddresses>
```

SO, in powershell I try to do this as a test, which fails:

```
$newNumber = [xml] '<value>555-1215</value>'
$newNode = $Request2.ImportNode($newNumber.value, $true)
$emailnode.AppendChild($newNode)
```

After some reading, I have figured out that if I do this, it suceeds:

```
$newNumber = [xml] '<value name="flubber">555-1215</value>'
$newNode = $Request2.ImportNode($newNumber.value, $true)
$emailnode.AppendChild($newNode)
```

So, I am stuck. I'm starting to wonder if I should use another function instead of importnode when I have several keys with the same name but different values.

As you guys probably have figured out by now, i'm not an expert in xml. ANy help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've indicated, there are pieces of XML that have been left out of the question so I've constructed my own rendition that hopefully adapts to the *real world* version.

First off...

```
$newNumber.value
```

... is of type string. [ImportNode(](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode(VS.80).aspx)) expects a **XmlNode** type as the first parameter. To get this, you can probably call a function like [get_DocumentElement()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement(VS.80).aspx) and/or [SelectSingleNode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb63z0tw(VS.80).aspx).

For example:

```
$Request2 = [xml]'<root><emailAddresses/></root>'
$newNumber = [xml]'<value>555-1215</value>'
$newNode = $Request2.ImportNode( $newNumber.get_DocumentElement(), $true )
$Request2.get_DocumentElement().SelectSingleNode( './emailAddresses' ).AppendChild( $newNode )
```

This should render the results that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
PS> $xml = [xml]'<addresses/>'
PS> $newNode = $xml.CreateElement('value')
PS> $newNode.InnerText = 'bob@bob.com'
PS> $xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($newNode) > $null
PS> $newNode = $xml.CreateElement('value')
PS> $newNode.InnerText = 'johnny@bob.com'
PS> $xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($newNode) > $null
PS> $xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml
<addresses><value>bob@bob.com</value><value>johnny@bob.com</value></addresses>
```